# Android and Youtube

Tags: android, youtube

Is it possible to setup the android app I am working on to open the youtube app and or navtive browser when clicked on anywhere in the app?

Thank you

Comment: What do you want? The question is not clear.... If you click in the view activity, you want to play a video in youtube? Please edit the question and give us more data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on Intents, it's Chapter 1. You can launch any app like you tube or browser.